# Highcharts bars are being offset

Tags: highcharts

I have a chart that is rendering bars with a slight offset. See image below. The blue bars are negative values, and the black bars are positive values, with the horizontal line marker being a net value. Notice how the black bars start slightly behind the 0 axis line.

This only seems to occur when our brand font is being used (the default font seems to have no issues). The font has no letter-spacing or font-feature-settings properties set. Any ideas why this might be happening and how I can fix it?

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve]. Would be good on either https://jsfiddle.net/ or https://codepen.io/

Comment: To workaround this issue, I wait until the chart begins rendering (and make the assumption that it is calculating the position of elements on chart) - and then 10ms later, I fire a timeout that applies a style targeting the .highcharts-axis-labels class which applies my font.

Comment: Please add a live demo or share the chart configuration. If your custom font is confidential please use another with the same properties to recreate the problem.